# Google SAML Error

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, google

I'm testing SSO with Google as the IDP into a sandbox. The button appears on the sandbox log in page, but when I use it, I cannot login to the sandbox.

Here is the log result:

1. Results   Last recorded SAML login failure: 
   2016-12-06T15:56:12.107Z Unexpected Exceptions   Ok

   1. Validating the Status   Ok
   2. Looking for an Authentication Statement   Ok
   3. Looking for a Conditions statement   Ok
   4. Checking that the timestamps in the assertion are valid   Ok
   5. Checking that the Attribute namespace matches, if provided   Not Provided
   6. Miscellaneous format confirmations   Ok
   7. Confirming Issuer matches   Ok
   8. Confirming a Subject Confirmation was provided and contains valid timestamps   Ok

   **9. Checking that the Audience matches   Audience problems

      The audience in the assertion did not match the allowed audiences

   Allowed audiences: [https://ideglobal--BDERP.cs62.my.salesforce.com]**

   10. Checking the Recipient   Ok   Organization Id that we expected: 00D5C0000000Mji   Organization Id that we found based on your
       assertion: 00D5C0000000Mji
   11. Validating the Signature   Is the response signed? false   Is the assertion signed? true   Is the correct certificate supplied in
       the keyinfo? true   Ok
   12. Checking that the Site URL Attribute contains a valid site url, if provided   Not Provided
   13. Looking for portal and organization id, if provided   Ok
   14. Checking if session security level is valid, if provided   Ok

Can you please help to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because from the google auth provider your audience value is mismatched .

> The  value is required and must match the Entity ID from the single sign-on configuration.

Recheck your configuration in the google apps and ensure the audience parameter is sent properly .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The fix was to change the Entity Id in Google on the "Service Provider Details" to exactly match Salesforce.

In Google I had the EntityId set as https://myorgname-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/

In Salesforce the SAML Single Sign-On Settings Entity ID was set to https://myorgname-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com

So something as simple as a "/" at the end was causing me headaches

I removed the "/" from Google and it worked.  Interestingly enough, adding it to Salesforce also works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case, just was missing a backslash at the end on the configuration

Regards